# Error importing API DATA into excel using power query

Tags: excel, odata

I am trying to import data to excel (latest version, Mac) from an API. I am very much an amateur but I have tried to research the issue with no success.

I have a well formed API request. When I paste the request into my browser it returns exactly the JSON I expect.

When I put the request into a text file and use Data/Get Data/Run Web Query it is able to retrieve the data as a lengthy string. So again, I know the request works.

When I try to execute the same request using Data/Get Data/Get Data/OData it returns the following error:

> An exception occurred: [DataFormat.Error] OData: The given URL
> neither points to an OData service or a feed

I haven't been able to find any documentation on what I need to do to turn an API request into an "OData service or a feed".

I greatly appreciate any help to solve that.

Thanks, Shawn

Comment: Sounds like the API you are using doesn't follow the OData standard as required by Excel. If you aren't able to change the way the API works you may need to find a different solution. For example you may need convert your lengthy string into the data format you want

Comment: For example looks like there are some sample OData feeds here https://www.odata.org/odata-services/ you could use these to satisfy yourself that Excel works, and possibly identify differences